# Managing and viewing branches in a GIST

Tags: git, github, gist

I created a gist and cloned it locally where I am happily managing it.  I also created a development branch and committed/pushed it (mainly as an exercise to understand git).  I can see and manage all of this using posh~git locally, but I can't find any trace of the new branch in my gists at https://gist.github.com or in my git repo's.

Is this a basic (and understandable) limitation of the gist interface or is there a way to select branches on a gist?

My motivation is to share rendered the gists using references to the included assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can't find any trace of the new branch in my gists at https://gist.github.com or in my git repo's.

Not only [gists](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/editing-and-sharing-content-with-gists/forking-and-cloning-gists) do not support branches, but the default branch has just (Feb. 2022) changed:

> ### [Gists Now Support Alternative Default Branch Names](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-02-10-gists-now-support-alternative-default-branch-names/)
>
> As you may or may not know, [gists are actually Git repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/editing-and-sharing-content-with-gists/forking-and-cloning-gists).
> New gists are now created with a default branch name of either **main** or the alternative default branch name you've defined in your user settings.

(See `git config --global init.defaultbranch xxx`, in [Git 2.28+, Q3 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983443/6309))

> This matches how other repositories are created on GitHub.
>
> - More information about [default branches](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches#about-the-default-branch)
> - How to [change the default branch name for new repositories](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-user-account-settings/managing-the-default-branch-name-for-your-repositories)
> - Learn more about the branch renaming effort in the [github/renaming repository](https://github.com/github/renaming/)

Answer (score 8):

This is a limitation of `gist.github.com`. If you need to use other features, make it an ordinary repo under `github.com` instead of a gist.

I am not aware of any feature that gist has that ordinary repos do *not* have.

Comment: So what happens to the commits on the remote? They are just there in the database but not available through the UI?

Comment: @CoolBlue Right. Any access over `git://` or `ssh://` is fully-featured, only the website has less features.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit naive, I don't understand what you mean.  When you say "the website" do you mean https://gist.github.com?

Comment: Right. Anything accessed over `http://` or `https://` using a web browser is a website.

Comment: OK... but, therefor, https://gist.github.com or https://github.com are websites, so I still can't resolve this statement: "Any access over git:// or ssh:// is fully-featured, only the website has less features."  "the website" is ambiguous to me.

Comment: gist.github.com and github.com are not websites, they're domain names. Accessing them over http/https gets you to websites, which have different sets of features. Accessing them over git or ssh connects you to entirely different software, with an entirely different set of features.

tl;dr: The web interface hosted at gist.github.com is more limited than that at github.com. However, the git and ssh interfaces at gist.github.com provide full git support.

Comment: *"I am not aware of any feature that gist has that ordinary repos do not have."* Actually there is 1 important feature that gist has that github does not: The ability publicly share something without the hassle of issues, pull requests, etc. And that is why they created gist and keep it limited. It was intended to be an improvement to pastebin, dpaste, etc.