# Add another file to existing GitHub Gist

Tags: gist

I've got [an existing GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/pcgeek86/2b869c0b6e93c907785c57d182b4bcd0), and I'd like to add another file to it.

The data model for the [GitHub Gist API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/) indicates that more than one file can be added to a Gist.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist

Note: **All files from the previous version of the gist are carried over by default if not included in the object.** Deletes can be performed by including the filename with a null object.

^So just pass the **files** object containing your new file with the PATCH request and it will be added to the gist

Answer (score 14):

Go to your Gist and click the Edit button at the top right.

The Gist editor will show your files in edit mode, then look at the bottom left and there you will find an 'Add file' button.

Click it and the cursor will be moved to the 'File name box..', type a name and click the 'Update gist' button at the bottom right.

:)

Comment: very little is intuitive on the gist section of github, even creating a new one is hard to figure out.

Answer (score 8):

Click `Edit`

[image: Edit Gist]

...and then `Add file`

[image: Add file]

Answer (score 3):

A command-line alternative is to `clone` the gist, `add` the file to the index, `commit` the change to the repository, and `push` the update to the remote repository:

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/…
git add …
git commit -m "…"
git push
```

In the interim, if the gist is altered using the site's <kbd>✍ Edit</kbd> button—say to update the gist's description—simply `pull` in the change when next at the command-line:

```
git pull
```

In this complete [example](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/ce4137a5b6015de88662c43c463add45), the file `JDBCPieTest.java` was added to the original gist. Examine the log to see the effect:

```
git shortlog
trashgod (7):
  <none>
  Add JDBCPieTest.java.
  <none>
  Add JDBCXYTest.java.
  <none>
  Rename JDBCTest.java -> JDBCCategoryTest.java.
  Refactor JDBCPieTest.java.
```

Comment: Man, you saved me. I was thinking of how to upload a big log, and that's the way to go!

Comment: This is also useful to add unsupported binary files to the gist – cool!

Comment: @trashgod Thank you for the response. Turns out it was just a problem of branches. I was pushing to master out of habit, and github shows branch 'main'.

Comment: More on [tag:github] gist branches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31017920/230513).